# isConnected() is freezes and returns nothing in web3.py

Tags: ether, web3.py, python

I use:
`python3.7`,
`web3==4.9.2`,
`Infura` and/or `own Node`.
After `web3` was initialized it returns `isConnected()` response only in first time, after that it freezes.

*web3.py*:

```
from web3 import Web3
from web3.gas_strategies.rpc import rpc_gas_price_strategy
from web3.providers.auto import load_provider_from_uri  


class Web3NotAvailableException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, rpc_url):
        self.rpc_url = rpc_url

    def __str__(self):
        return f'WEB3_RPC_URL: {self.rpc_url}'


def get_web3():
    logger.debug('Getting web3 instance')
    if hasattr(get_web3, '_web3_instance'):
        logger.warn('Here 1')
        _web3_instance = getattr(get_web3, '_web3_instance')
    else:
        logger.warn('Here 2')
        _web3_instance = Web3(load_provider_from_uri(settings.WEB3_RPC_URL))
        _web3_instance.eth.setGasPriceStrategy(rpc_gas_price_strategy)
        setattr(get_web3, '_web3_instance', _web3_instance)

    logger.warn('Before isConnected()')
    if not _web3_instance.isConnected():
        logger.warn('Here 3')
        _web3_instance = None
        raise Web3NotAvailableException(settings.WEB3_RPC_URL)

    logger.warn('Finish')
    return _web3_instance
```

*logs*:

```
DEBUG 07/06/2021 16:30:13 | [ web3.py:46 ] Getting web3 instance
WARNING 07/06/2021 16:30:13 | [ web3.py:51 ] Here 2
WARNING 07/06/2021 16:30:13 | [ web3.py:56 ] Before isConnected()
WARNING 07/06/2021 16:30:13 | [ web3.py:62 ] Finish
DEBUG 07/06/2021 16:30:15 | [ web3.py:46 ] Getting web3 instance
WARNING 07/06/2021 16:30:15 | [ web3.py:48 ] Here 1
WARNING 07/06/2021 16:30:15 | [ web3.py:56 ] Before isConnected()
```

and after that docker container freezes and happen nothing. Although `celery` should pushes tasks every 30 sec.

But if i use ganache locally everything works.

```
DEBUG 07/06/2021 16:59:37 | [ web3.py:46 ] Getting web3 instance
WARNING 07/06/2021 16:59:37 | [ web3.py:51 ] Here 2
WARNING 07/06/2021 16:59:37 | [ web3.py:56 ] Before isConnected()
WARNING 07/06/2021 16:59:37 | [ web3.py:62 ] Finish
################################################
DEBUG 07/06/2021 17:00:11 | [ web3.py:46 ] Getting web3 instance
WARNING 07/06/2021 17:00:11 | [ web3.py:48 ] Here 1
WARNING 07/06/2021 17:00:11 | [ web3.py:56 ] Before isConnected()
WARNING 07/06/2021 17:00:11 | [ web3.py:62 ] Finish
################################################
DEBUG 07/06/2021 17:00:41 | [ web3.py:46 ] Getting web3 instance
WARNING 07/06/2021 17:00:41 | [ web3.py:48 ] Here 1
WARNING 07/06/2021 17:00:41 | [ web3.py:56 ] Before isConnected()
WARNING 07/06/2021 17:00:41 | [ web3.py:62 ] Finish
```

What wrong ?

Comment: Someone had similar problems and it was related to Celery and async issues. They had to switch to gevent or similar to solve it. I am just remembering this from web3.py Discord chat.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa , thnx, you've just given me decision )

Comment: Don't forget to mark your own answer as correct.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa , "You can't vote for your own post" if you about it

Comment: You can still use "Correct answer" button, not voting.

Comment: oh, sorry, now i understand, leave the link here -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i moved `web3` initialization to settings file, now it it's initialize one time and i get the web3-result already for `Celery`:

*settings/production.py*:

```
from web3 import Web3
from web3.gas_strategies.rpc import rpc_gas_price_strategy
from web3.providers.auto import load_provider_from_uri
from django.conf import settings

from eth_watcher.web3 import Web3NotAvailableException


##################
# different variables here
##################
 
def get_web3():
    _web3_instance = Web3(load_provider_from_uri(settings.WEB3_RPC_URL))
    _web3_instance.eth.setGasPriceStrategy(rpc_gas_price_strategy)

    if not _web3_instance.isConnected():
        _web3_instance = None
        raise Web3NotAvailableException(settings.WEB3_RPC_URL)

    return _web3_instance


W3 = get_web3()
```

*web3.py*:

```
class Web3NotAvailableException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, rpc_url):
        self.rpc_url = rpc_url

    def __str__(self):
        return f'WEB3_RPC_URL: {self.rpc_url}'


def get_web3():
    return settings.W3
```